# Control de ActionEvent al almacenar objetos en un arrayList

Tags: java

Buenas estaba desarrollando un programa sencillito que almacenará encuestas pasandole una serie de datos para crear los objetos de tipo encuesta.

El problema que tengo es al controlar el evento de botón, que desencadena que se almacenen diferentes encuestas en mi arrayList, ya que si le pongo un for, para establecer el numero de encuestas que quiero que almacene, al pulsar el boton me las almacena todas de corrido, y si no le pongo el for, pues siempre me almacena la encuesta en la posición 1, del arrayList.

No se si debería utilizar un iterator para controlar la inserción de encuestas una vez se pulsa el botón, y se desencadena el ActionEvent, o como debería proceder.

A continuación paso el código del Escuchador o Listener que controla dicho evento:

```
package controlador;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import modelo.Encuesta;
import vista.VentanaEncuesta;

public class Controlador implements ActionListener {

    private VentanaEncuesta ve;

    public Controlador(VentanaEncuesta ve) {
        this.ve = ve;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ArrayList<Encuesta>listaEncuestas = new ArrayList<Encuesta>();
        Encuesta encuesta = ve.obtenerDatos();
        boolean completo;

        //No para al llegar a 10 encuestas almacenadas.
        if(encuesta!=null) {
            completo = false;
            // Si no pongo el for guarda solo guarda
            //una encuesta en la primera posición del arrayList, y si se lo pongo no funciona.
            // Si lo cambio por un array al guardar la primera encuesta, se queda colgado.
            if(e.getSource().equals(ve.getBtnGuardarDatos()) && !completo) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                    listaEncuestas.add(encuesta);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ve, "Encuesta " + listaEncuestas.size() + " almacenada correctamente",
                            "¡Exito!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    if(listaEncuestas.size()==10) {
                        completo=true;  
                    }   
                }
                }else if(e.getSource().equals(ve.getBtnGuardarDatos()) && completo) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ve, "El número de encuestas máximo (10) ya se ha alcanzado", "¡Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            //TODO: EL botón mostrarInforme no funciona.
            if (e.getSource().equals(ve.getBtnGenerarInforme())) {
                String Informe = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < listaEncuestas.size(); i++) {

                    Informe = ve.calcularPorcentajeH_M(listaEncuestas.get(i), listaEncuestas.size()); 
                    Informe += ve.calcularPorcentajeTrabajadores(listaEncuestas.get(i), listaEncuestas.size());
                    Informe += ve.calcularSueldoPromedio(listaEncuestas.get(i));

                }
                ve.getTxtAInforme().setText(Informe);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como digo el problema esta que una vez desencadeno el evento de botón, me añade de corrido todas las posiciones del ArrayList, y no se como controlar cada interacción del for, para que pueda insertar una Encuesta cada vez que pulse el boton.

Estoy empezando con esto de Swing, asi que estoy un poco verde.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de ante mano!

Comment: No es cuestión de swing sino de orden en el código. Lo primero sería discriminar qué botón se ha pulsado, porque las acciones son completamente distintas. Una vez sepas que el botón es el de guardar, obtienes una encuesta y la metes en la lista. Ese `for` te está metiendo la misma encuesta una vez en cada vuelta. Mete solo una. La metes y fin. Ya está. La función termina. El otro botón no hace nada porque lo has metido dentro del `if` de si la encuesta no es `null`. Y nunca parece que lo sea. Dale una vuelta al código y piensa un poco mejor el diseño. Creas una lista cada vez que pulsas...

Answer (score 0):

el problema que he notado en tu codigo, es que al recibir el evento de pulsacion, estas creando una lista de encuestas nuevamente, es por esto que solo te guarda 1 sola lista, la solucion que he encontrado, es cambiar la lista de encuestas a una variable global, de esta forma, las encuestas que has guardado anteriormente se mantendra y solo agregaras la nueva encuesta.

```
package controlador;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import modelo.Encuesta;
import vista.VentanaEncuesta;

public class Controlador implements ActionListener {

    private VentanaEncuesta ve;

    //La lista de encuestas almacenadas tambien debe ser global
        ArrayList<Encuesta>listaEncuestas = new ArrayList<Encuesta>();
    public Controlador(VentanaEncuesta ve) {
        this.ve = ve;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Aqui estas creando una nueva lista cada vez que se pulsa el boton, es por esto que solo te guarda 1 a la vez.
        //ArrayList<Encuesta>listaEncuestas = new ArrayList<Encuesta>();
        Encuesta encuesta = ve.obtenerDatos();
        boolean completo;

        //No para al llegar a 10 encuestas almacenadas.
        if(encuesta!=null) {
            completo = false;
            // Si no pongo el for guarda solo guarda
            //una encuesta en la primera posición del arrayList, y si se lo pongo no funciona.
            // Si lo cambio por un array al guardar la primera encuesta, se queda colgado.
            if(e.getSource().equals(ve.getBtnGuardarDatos()) && !completo) {

                    listaEncuestas.add(encuesta);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ve, "Encuesta " + listaEncuestas.size() + " almacenada correctamente",
                            "¡Exito!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    if(listaEncuestas.size()==10) {
                        completo=true;  
                    }

                }else if(e.getSource().equals(ve.getBtnGuardarDatos()) && completo) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ve, "El número de encuestas máximo (10) ya se ha alcanzado", "¡Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            //TODO: EL botón mostrarInforme no funciona.
            if (e.getSource().equals(ve.getBtnGenerarInforme())) {
                String Informe = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < listaEncuestas.size(); i++) {

                    Informe = ve.calcularPorcentajeH_M(listaEncuestas.get(i), listaEncuestas.size()); 
                    Informe += ve.calcularPorcentajeTrabajadores(listaEncuestas.get(i), listaEncuestas.size());
                    Informe += ve.calcularSueldoPromedio(listaEncuestas.get(i));

                }
                ve.getTxtAInforme().setText(Informe);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación lo probe y si funciona, aunque finalmente me decante por crear una clase a parte que tuviera como atributo un arrayList, e inicializarlo en el constructor del mismo, creando un método para poder añadir los datos.